# Unexpected result when filtering one object array against two other object arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to filter out objects from array "a" that match with objects in array "b" and "c". here is a link to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8mwu3aq5/4/) to test the code.

Here is what I currently have:

```js
const a = [{
  "name": "sondre",
  "uq_id": "abc1"
}, {
  "name": "sofie",
  "uq_id": "abc2"
}, {
  "name": "casper",
  "uq_id": "abc3"
}, {
  "name": "odin",
  "uq_id": "abc4"
}];

const b = [{
  "name": "sondre",
  "uq_id": "abc1"
}, {
  "name": "odin",
  "uq_id": "abc4"
}];

const c = [{
  "name": "casper",
  "uq_id": "abc3"
}];

function sort(a, b, c) {
  result = [];
  console.log(result);
  if (b !== null) {
    result = a.filter(function(item) {
      return !b.includes(item.uq_id);
    })
  }
  if (c !== null) {
    result = result.filter(function(item) {
      return !c.includes(item.uq_id);
    })
  }
  console.log(result);
}

sort(a, b, c);
```

I expect the following output:

```
[{name="sofie", uq_id="abc2"}]
```

But for some reason it outputs:

```
[{name="sondre", uq_id="abc1"},
{name="sofie", uq_id="abc2"},
{name="casper", uq_id="abc3"},
{name="odin", uq_id="abc4"}]
```

Does anyone know how I can get this to work as I intended it?

Comment: *"heres a link to jsfiddle to test the code"* Please do your runnable example **here, on-site** using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: Why is the function called `sort`? It doesn't do any sorting.

Comment: ^ indeed, it does more "filtering". Or rather intersection between three arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the goal is to filter out entries from `a` whose `name` matches an entry on either `b` or `c`, you can't use `includes` unless the entries in `a`, `b`, and `c` refer to the **same** objects (not just equivalent ones).

Assuming they don't, you can use `some` to find out whether an array contains a match for a `name`. You'll want to use `&&` to see that there's no match in either `b` or `c`:

```
const filtered = a.filter(entry => {
    return !b.some(({name}) => entry.name === name) &&
           !c.some(({name}) => entry.name === name);
});
```

Live Copy:

```js
const a = [{
  "name": "sondre",
  "uq_id": "abc1"
}, {
  "name": "sofie",
  "uq_id": "abc2"
}, {
  "name": "casper",
  "uq_id": "abc3"
}, {
  "name": "odin",
  "uq_id": "abc4"
}];

const b = [{
  "name": "sondre",
  "uq_id": "abc1"
}, {
  "name": "odin",
  "uq_id": "abc4"
}];

const c = [{
  "name": "casper",
  "uq_id": "abc3"
}];

function filter(a, b, c) {
    const filtered = a.filter(entry => {
        return !b.some(({name}) => entry.name === name) &&
               !c.some(({name}) => entry.name === name);
    });
    return filtered;
}

console.log(filter(a, b, c));
```

That can also be expressed with `every`, whichever you prefer:

```
const filtered = a.filter(entry => {
    return b.every(({name}) => entry.name !== name) &&
           c.every(({name}) => entry.name !== name);
});
```

If `b` and `c` are **really** large (hundreds of thousands of entries, perhaps millions) that could be inefficient enough to justify creating `Set`s of names first:

```
const names = new Set([
  ...b.map(({name}) => name),
  ...c.map(({name}) => name)
]);
const filtered = a.filter(entry => {
    return !names.has(entry.name);
});
```

Or you might just do that for preference or clarity.

Live Copy:

```js
const a = [{
  "name": "sondre",
  "uq_id": "abc1"
}, {
  "name": "sofie",
  "uq_id": "abc2"
}, {
  "name": "casper",
  "uq_id": "abc3"
}, {
  "name": "odin",
  "uq_id": "abc4"
}];

const b = [{
  "name": "sondre",
  "uq_id": "abc1"
}, {
  "name": "odin",
  "uq_id": "abc4"
}];

const c = [{
  "name": "casper",
  "uq_id": "abc3"
}];

function filter(a, b, c) {
    const names = new Set([
      ...b.map(({name}) => name),
      ...c.map(({name}) => name)
    ]);
    const filtered = a.filter(entry => {
        return !names.has(entry.name);
    });
    return filtered;
}

console.log(filter(a, b, c));
```

Comment: Apologies, I had a silly logic error (and typo) that I didn't catch until doing the runnable examples. :-/

Comment: How would this handle B or C being empty, undefined or null?

Comment: @SondreLjovshin - Empty isn't a problem. If they might be `undefined` or `null`, you'll want to handle that. Probably the easiest way is `if (!b) { b = []; } if (!c) { c = []; }` before you start the filtering.

Answer (score 1):

`b` and `c` are arrays of objects it only includes objects. You need to use `some()` on then to compare `uq_id`

```js
const a = [{
    "name": "sondre",
    "uq_id": "abc1"
}, {
    "name": "sofie",
    "uq_id": "abc2"
}, {
    "name": "casper",
    "uq_id": "abc3"
}, {
    "name": "odin",
    "uq_id": "abc4"
}];

const b = [{
    "name": "sondre",
    "uq_id": "abc1"
}, {
    "name": "odin",
    "uq_id": "abc4"
}];

const c = [{
    "name": "casper",
    "uq_id": "abc3"
}];

sort(a, b, c);



function sort(a, b, c) {
    let result = [];
    if (b !== null) {
        result = a.filter(function(item) {
            return !b.some(x => x.uq_id === item.uq_id);
        })
    }
    if (c !== null) {
        result = result.filter(function(item) {
            return !c.some(x => x.uq_id === item.uq_id);
        })
    }
    console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this seems to resolve my problem in the most efficient way

Answer (score 0):

Single filter is enough :

```js
const a = [ { "name": "sondre", "uq_id": "abc1" }, 
            { "name": "sofie" , "uq_id": "abc2" }, 
            { "name": "casper", "uq_id": "abc3" }, 
            { "name": "odin"  , "uq_id": "abc4" } ];

const b = [ { "name": "sondre", "uq_id": "abc1" }, 
            { "name": "odin"  , "uq_id": "abc4" } ];

const c = [ { "name": "casper", "uq_id": "abc3" } ];


const result = a.filter(x => !b.some(y => x.uq_id === y.uq_id) 
                          && !c.some(y => x.uq_id === y.uq_id));

console.log(result);
```